# What do I need to do to send out Protobuf serialized Data using C# ASP .NET web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm new to protobuf and fairly new to asp .net. so I might need help on this. I have this code snippet for my PersonsController:

```
public class PersonController : ApiController
{
    [ProtoContract]
    public class Person
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public string First { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(3)]
        public string Last { get; set; }
    }
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<Person> Get()
    {
        List<Person> myList = new List<Person> { 
            new Person { ID = 0, First = "Judy", Last  = "Lee" },
            new Person { ID = 1, First = "John", Last  = "Doe" },
            new Person { ID = 2, First = "George", Last  = "Poole" },
        };

        return myList;
    }
}
```

and I'm wondering if that's enough to be able to send out the protobuf data and be consumed by other applications?

I'm trying to access it directly in google chrome and all I'm getting is an XML format of the data.

```html
<ArrayOfPersonController.Person xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SampleSerialize.Controllers">
  <PersonController.Person>
    <First>Judy</First>
    <ID>0</ID>
    <Last>Lee</Last>
  </PersonController.Person>
  <PersonController.Person>
    <First>John</First>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Last>Doe</Last>
  </PersonController.Person>
  <PersonController.Person>
    <First>George</First>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Last>Poole</Last>
  </PersonController.Person>
</ArrayOfPersonController.Person>
```

How do I know if I'm able to send out the serialized data?

Comment: you should define the data format to send out your api, XML, JSON, plain text, etc

Comment: this could help http://www.infoworld.com/article/2982579/application-architecture/working-with-protocol-buffers-in-web-api.html

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to do a couple of things:

1. **You need a web client that actually asks for protobuf-serialized content** in the request's `Accept` [header](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html). Chrome doesn't do this--it only asks for things like text/html, image/*, etc... stuff you'd expect a web browser to ask for. There isn't a standard content type for protobuf, so you can just define your own--many people use `application/x-protobuf`. There are Chrome developer tools like [Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/advanced%20rest%20client) that let you exercise REST APIs from a browser and set your request headers however you'd like.
2. **On the Web API side, you need to create and register your own media formatter.** There's a good walkthrough [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters). You'll probably derive from [BufferedMediaTypeFormatter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formatting.bufferedmediatypeformatter.aspx) to do the protobuf (de/)serialization, and you'll want to configure this class to handle `application/x-protobuf` requests. Then you'll need to register it with the Web API pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for the response:

1. I can see that ARC is detecting application/x-protobuf automatically even without setting the header to "Accept: application/protobuf". Does that mean that it's automatically decoding the message?

2. I have the "config.Formatters.Insert(0, new ProtoBufFormatter());" in the WebApiConfig.cs. Should that be the same as you've mentioned?

Comment: If both the request's `Accept` header and the response's `Content-Type` header are set to application/x-protobuf then yes, ARC is doing things right. Just make sure ARC isn't asking for any additional content types in the request. And assuming your ProtoBufFormatter class came from [here](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebApiContrib.Formatting.ProtoBuf/blob/master/src/WebApiContrib.Formatting.ProtoBuf/ProtoBufFormatter.cs), yes, you're doing the right thing in WebApiConfig.cs. Is ARC still getting back XML in the response?

Comment: yup, the accept header in ARC and the Response.ContentType in the code are both set to application/x-protobuf. and yup the ProtoBufFormatter class came from the one you linked ( actually got it from NuGet ). I'm getting just plain text in the response in ARC. Is this expected? I'm expecting that it should be binary.